# Error checking on gapi.client.load

Tags: google-drive-api

I am writing javascript code to access Google Drive. The code examples show calls like:
    gapi.client.load('drive','v2',callbackfunction);

How do I check to see that this call was successful?

I have tried:
    result = gapi.client.load('drive','v2',callbackfunction);
But result is undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no result to be returned from that call. It's simply loading a library. When the library has finished loading the callback will be called.